# Mongoose - Why we make "mongoose.Promise = global.Promise" when setting a mongoose module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm working with Mongoose. I have seen a lot of developers make the following command:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Then I was curious to see what is the original value of `mongoose.Promise` . I have entered in my editor the following command:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

console.log("promise: ", mongoose.Promise);
```

My console returned me :

> promise:  function Promise() { [native code] }

Okay, so why make the command `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise` since the Mongoose's promise already returns a native code ? I don't understand the point, if someone can help us to understand, would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is legacy code from older examples that isn't needed with Mongoose 5.

Mongoose 4 relied on its own promise implementation, `mpromise`. `mongoose.Promise` wasn't necessarily `Promise` global.

As [Mongoose 4 documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#promise_Promise) states:

> Mongoose 5.0 will use native promises by default (or bluebird,
>   if native promises are not present) but still
>   support plugging in your own ES6-compatible promises library. Mongoose 5.0
>   will not support mpromise.

Though the statement about Bluebird is no longer true; Mongoose 5 dropped the support of Node versions that don't have native promises.

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

may still be needed if `global.Promise` was assigned with another implementation (e.g. Bluebird) after Mongoose was imported, though a better thing would be to assign `global.Promise = Bluebird` earlier instead.

Comment: Just to confirm, we don't need to use `mongoose.promise = global.promise`? We can use native promise? Also, By native promise you mean `.then`, `promise`, `promise.all `?

Comment: Yes, we don't need it. Other promise implementations may have compatible methods too. By native promise I mean that `model.save(...)` returns an instance of `Promise`.

Answer (score 31):

Mongoose maintainer here. If you're using Mongoose 5, please remove `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;`. That line was used to address the below deprecation warning with [promises in Mongoose 4](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/promise#the-mongoosepromise-property):

```
WARNING: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead
```

It does nothing in Mongoose 5. You should only use `mongoose.Promise` in Mongoose 5 if you want to use [your own promise library](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#plugging-in-your-own-promises-library) with Mongoose, like Bluebird or Q.

There's also a little more about `mongoose.Promise` here: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/promise#the-mongoosepromise-property

Answer (score 3):

If we want to use mongoose in different position inside the codes it must  be viewed as global mode,   that's why we need to set mongoose as :

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

we used just in the point when we want to get connected in to  MongoDB  database  :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoDB = ' database url ';

mongoose.connect(mongoDB);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connection.on('error',console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

you need to create  schema  and do your own model after

Answer (score 0):

First, mongoose uses Promise for Async applications. In new versions it can be:

```
mongoose.connect("URL").then("what you need to happen after the connection is done").catch("when the error happened")
```

Therefore, I used promise and global to use mongoose anywhere as Async when writing mongoose.