# Working on Nodejs that uses MongoDB . I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

When I am trying to enter new dishes into the collection it returns the new dishes but after that it shows  'TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined'.

Tried uninstalling promise and installing again.
Also I tried with es6-promise.

**dishes.js**

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const dishSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    },
    description :{
        type : String,
        required : true
      }
    },{

    timestamps : true
});
 var  Dishes = mongoose.model('Dish',dishSchema);

module.exports = Dishes;
```

And **index.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

const Dishes = require('./models/dishes');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';

const connect = mongoose.connect(url);
connect.then((db) => {
    console.log('Connected correctly to Server');
    var newDish = Dishes({
        name : "Uthapizza",
        description : 'test'
    });

    newDish.save()
    .then((dish) =>{
        console.log(dish);
       return Dishes.find({}).exec();
    })
    .then((dishes) =>{
        console.log(dishes);
        return db.Collection('dishes').drop();

    })
    .then(() =>{
        return db.close();
    })
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

});
```

The code is working fine but I don't know why it is throwing an error in the end.

Comment: what version of NodeJS are you using? Promise should be already built in... Plus, it means that `es6-promise` doesn't exists in your node_modules.

Comment: @EliyaCohen - if `es6-promise` didn't exist, the error would be different

Comment: what line number is given in the error message - which line of your code does it show as having the error

Comment: ypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined
    at Mongoose.NativeCollection [as Collection] (C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\nodejs\node-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:25:26)

Comment: I have uninstalled promise and es6-promise but the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method. I hope it helps.

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Note: use global.Promise instead of bluebird
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  promiseLibrary: global.Promise
});

....
```

Comment: Hi Grey, I tried this but the error persists. Out of curiosity could you tell how this code works?

Comment: Hi Yajnaseni, that's surprising to hear. This may answer your question: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862570/mongoose-why-we-make-mongoose-promise-global-promise-when-setting-a-mongoo) here.